# Is there a way to get at the UICollectionViewCell created by UICollectionViewDropCoordinator.drop(_:to:)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am implementing dragging and dropping of images from other app (e.g. Safari) into a UICollectionView of my own app. I created a placeholder cell with a spinner in it from storyboard so the placeholder cell would get created and spinner would spin when loading the image from the url after dragging and dropping.

My **problem** is that the spinner would no longer spin for drops after the first one. The same placeholder cell has been reused, and I am kind of sure that the spinner has stopped animating after the first drop and therefore it doesn't spin for further drops.

My **question** is how I can get the reference to the placeholder cell or, just the spinner so that I can do `startAnimating()` from the second drop on?

The below code is a part from `collectionView(_:performDropWith:)`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
    let destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath ?? IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    let placeHolderContext = coordinator.drop(item.dragItem,
                                              to: UICollectionViewDropPlaceholder(insertionIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, reuseIdentifier: "dropPlaceholderCell"))

    ...

    let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: imageARAndURL["imageURL"] as! URL)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let imageData = urlContents {
            imageARAndURL["image"] = UIImage(data: imageData) ?? UIImage(named: "imageNotFound")
        } else {
            imageARAndURL["image"] = UIImage(named: "imageNotFound")
        }
        placeHolderContext.commitInsertion(dataSourceUpdates: { (insertionIndexPath) in
            self.imageARAndURLs.insert(imageARAndURL, at: insertionIndexPath.item)
        })
    }
```